# WebStorm slow and freezing unknown cause

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I use WebStorm primarially to write code for my Express web server. WebStorm hangs when I am moving between lines or entering characters. It all started when I cloned and opened a new project that contained Cordova/Ionic stuff and let the IDE install some plugins for that.

Now I have no idea what plugins I installed or settings I changed, but I have tried EVERYTHING including uninstalling Node JS, reinstalling the latest WebStorm, clearing project IDEA folder, etc.

Comment: Just a few tips: google around for tips and tricks on speeding up IntelliJ/Webstorm. Also, in your project structure, right click any directories that aren't part of your code explicitly and select 'Mark Directory As...' --> Excluded. This will prevent webstorm from indexing those files. A good example of this is node_modules, if you have any in your project. You (probably) don't need Webstorm to have all those files constantly scanned and indexed, so mark the directory as excluded to prevent that.

Comment: All this was caused by opening a big CORDOVA/IONIC app and installing the recommended plugins. What folders in my operating system do I have to blow away to get to a default state?!?

Comment: With these kinds of issues you better contact JetBrains support directly: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new as resolving such issue quite often requires quite a bit of information (performance report/IDE logs/thread dumps and other stuff)

Comment: Changing my configs helped me a lot; I used this SO post as a template. It fixed all of my issues:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38339941/webstorm-slow-and-freezing-unknown-cause

Answer (score 4):

@matmo's answer worked well for me. I'm using Webstorm for an Ionic2 project and I hadn't excluded much. For me I excluded all but the ./src folder and the files in the root path of the project.

No more freezing (or rage).

Answer (score 1):

@matmo's also worked for me, however I noticed the real difference when I marked the www folder as excluded.  Webstorm would freeze for a fraction of a second even clicking between each folder to mark them as excluded.  Once I excluded the www I was free from the aggravating freeze.

I am using Webstorm 2017.1.4 and Ionic 3.8.1 on a 2016 Macbook Pro 13.

Comment: It should be on comment section.@jlingo

Comment: @RohitPoudel Possibly because of insufficient rep!

Comment: @RohitPoudel yep, I tried but... insufficient rep. :(

Answer (score 0):

My problem was here:

'Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries'

The 'node_modules' directory had a minus (-) sign, meaning some items in it were enabled. I clicked it twice to uncheck it.

[image]